# Qual a lógica e como surgiram os nomes dos meses?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica

Já ouvi dizer que alguns nomes são homenagens a deuses e outros ao número de referência do meses em *latim*, mas parece que está tudo bagunçado. A lógica não deveria ser assim:

> 07 - Setembro 
>   08 - Outubro 
>  
>   09 - Novembro 
>   10 - Dezembro

Qual a lógica e como surgiram os nomes dos meses?

Comment: http://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/como-surgiram-nomes-meses-ano-493925.shtml. São todos números do velho calendário romano.

Comment: Nomes de imperadores romanos. Julio Cesar :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A história conta que os romanos, bem influenciados por seus deuses, foram os responsáveis para a criação dos nomes dos meses no nosso calendário.

- **Janeiro:** ou *Ianuarius*, foi uma homenagem ao deus Jano
- **Fevereiro:** ou *Februarius*, foi uma homenagem ao deus Fébruo, o senhor da morte e da purificação.
- **Março:** ou *Martius*, foi uma homenagem ao deus da guerra, Marte.
- **Abril**: ou *Aprilis*, que significa abrir, numa referência à germinação das culturas. Outra hipótese sugere que Abril seja derivado de *Aprus*, o nome etrusco de Vénus, deusa do amor e da paixão. Outra versão é que se relaciona com Afrodite, nome grego da deusa Vênus, que teria nascido de uma espuma do mar que, em grego antigo, se dizia abril.
- **Maio**: derivado da deusa romana Bona Dea da fertilidade. Outras versões apontam que a origem se deve à deusa grega Maya, mãe de Hermes.
- **Junho**:  derivado da deusa romana Juno, mulher do deus Júpiter. Outra versão diz que deriva do nome de um clã romano chamado *Junius*.
- **Julho:** homenagem ao imperador romano Júlio César, sendo antes chamado *Quintilis* em latim, dado que era o quinto mês do Calendário Romano, que começava em março. Também recebeu esse nome por ser o mês em que César nasceu.
- **Agosto:** ou *Augustus*, é chamado assim por decreto em honra do imperador César Augusto. Antes dessa mudança, agosto era denominado *Sextilis* ou *Sextil*, visto que era o sexto mês no calendário de Rômulo.
- **Setembro - Dezembro:** seguem a lógica *septem* (7), *octo* (8), *novem* (9), *decem* (10). Lembrando que o calendário romano começava em março.

**Fonte**

- [wikipedia.com, "Month"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month)
- [soportugues.com.br, "Por que os meses têm esses nomes?"](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/curiosidades/nomes_dos_meses.php)

Answer (score 3):

Originalmente no calendário romano o ano começava com o mês de Martius (hoje Março).

Antes havia outros meses com nomes numéricos, como Quinctilis (Julho) e Sextilis (Agosto), mas estes não existem nas línguas neolatinas como o português.

Comment: Será que em vez de `não existem (em)` ficaria melhor `não foram adotados (por)`?

Comment: [Como surgiram os meses do ano](http://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/como-surgiram-nomes-meses-ano-493925.shtml)